# c# .net SOAP API add a prefix to namespace

Tags: c#, .net, soap

We are calling a SOAP Service using .net in C#. We added the service reference. We receive an error when calling the method using the api. Our vendor determined that we are not sending a prefix in the namespace. I have included the .net generated code from the resources.cs file. My question is how can we add a prefix to the existing class in order to resolve the issue.

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="getLocationsByCriteria", WrapperNamespace="http://services.timecommerce.timetrade.com/ws", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class getLocationsByCriteriaRequest {
    
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://services.timecommerce.timetrade.com/ws", Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public SystemRefresh.ConfigurationServices.locationSearchCriteria locationSearchCriteria;
    
    public getLocationsByCriteriaRequest() {
    }
    
    public getLocationsByCriteriaRequest(SystemRefresh.ConfigurationServices.locationSearchCriteria locationSearchCriteria) {
        this.locationSearchCriteria = locationSearchCriteria;
    }
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="getLocationsByCriteriaResponse", WrapperNamespace="http://services.timecommerce.timetrade.com/ws", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class getLocationsByCriteriaResponse {
    
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://services.timecommerce.timetrade.com/ws", Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public SystemRefresh.ConfigurationServices.locationListResult @return;
    
    public getLocationsByCriteriaResponse() {
    }
    
    public getLocationsByCriteriaResponse(SystemRefresh.ConfigurationServices.locationListResult @return) {
        this.@return = @return;
    }
}
```

Working body tag in SOAP UI below

```
 <soapenv:Body>
  <ws:getLocationsByCriteria>
     <locationSearchCriteria>           
        <locationExternalId>sonoram3n</locationExternalId>
     <locationGroupId>0</locationGroupId>
     </locationSearchCriteria>
  </ws:getLocationsByCriteria>
 </soapenv:Body>
```

Failing tags from the current process below

```
 <s:Body>
 <getLocationsByCriteria>
   <locationSearchCriteria>
   <locationExternalId>sonoram3n</locationExternalId>
   <locationGroupId>0</locationGroupId>
 </locationSearchCriteria>
 </getLocationsByCriteria>
 </s:Body>
```

Comment: The `soapenv:`, `ws:` and `s:` _prefixes_ you show are meaningless without an namespace declaration.  If `soapenv:` and `s:` both refer to the same namepace, then `<soapenv:Body>` and `<s:Body>` are equivalent. It's the lack of a namespace on the `<getLocationsByCriteria>` (compared to `<ws:getLocationsByCriteria>`) that makes the difference.  Sorry, I it's been about a decade or so since I used WCF, I don't remember the right attribute incantation needed to fix your issue

Comment: Yes, soapenv: and s: both refer to the same namepace. The working xml was performed in SOUP UI while the failing XML was generated from .net